# How to set cookie with bootstrap data-toggle="collapse" and js.cookie.js?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

I have a form with a bootstrap data-toogle="collapse".

If the user expands the advanced form fields I would like to set a cookie with [js.cookie.js](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie).

If the user hides the advanced form fields the cookie should be deleted.

If the site with the form is shown, the cookie should be evaluated and the form expanded or not.

How do I do this?

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="therapistSearch-AdvancedSearch" class="col-md-4 control-label">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="##collapseAdvancedSearch" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Erweiterte Suche
        </a></label>                                
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseAdvancedSearch">
    bla bla
</div>
```

Comment: var foo=$("##collapseAdvancedSearch").attr('aria-expanded');
alert(foo);
Why is foo in everycase undefined?

Comment: (Boolean($("##collapseAdvancedSearch").is(':visible'))) does work